# SAP Business one

Tags: sapb1

while using SAP Business One, we have database called SBO-COMMON, unfortunately i have deleted the Database SBO-COMMON without having any backup. could you help me to get SBO-COMMON database

Answer (score 2):

@indu, the only option you have is run the installer of sap b1 (server), the installer will create the database `SBO-COMMON` again.

Comment: Yes only way to recover it is to re-install B1 server

Answer (score 1):

The SBO-Common database contains meta data about your company databases. If it has been deleted you have lost none of your company data but you wont be able to connect to your database.

Simply re-install the SAP B1 server software to recreate the SBO-COMMON database.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't recover SBO-COMMON once it is deleted. However, you can create with new set of sample databases by installing SAP B1 server again. But, please remember that the new SBO-COMMON will not have the list of previous databases whatever deleted before.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are in the initial phase you can run the installer again so that the base is created and you also have the option of attaching more test bases.

Answer (score 0):

You have ro reinstall SAP B1 and then restore your company db